# The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error (VB PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net

I have this connection issue when connecting a PHP to MySQL via VB.net

The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. The die statement comes back as "Access Denied"

**FOUND THIS ERROR**

```
    Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/example/public_html/load.php on line 6
[27-Oct-2017 22:36:42 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() in /home/example/public_html/load.php:6
```

**Visual Basic:**

```
Function Checkban(AuthenticationPage As String, Username As String, Serial As String) As Boolean
    Dim wc As New WebClient()
    wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    Dim Data As String = String.Format("Username={0}&Password={1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Username), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Serial))
    Dim ResponseBytes() As Byte = wc.UploadData(AuthenticationPage, "POST", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data))
    Dim Response As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ResponseBytes)
    If Response.Contains("Correct") Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

**PHP:**
[image: Image - Sorry, couldn't put code]

**Execute:**

```
If CheckUser("http://example/load.php?=", TextBox9.Text, TextBox10.Text) Then
    MsgBox("Correct", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
Else
    MsgBox("Incorrect", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
End If
```

If anyone can help or guide me to fix this issue, that will be great!! Thanks!

Comment: A 500 error almost always means that your code threw an exception. Can you tell if it got to one of your die statements?  I'm not really familiar with php, but I'd think the errors would be logged somewhere.  Check that.

Comment: The die statements comes back as access denied

Comment: Ah! the error message you found and added to the question should help.  Sounds like a MySQL library is missing.  I don't know enough about PHP to help with that, but I upvoted your question so maybe somebody who can help will see it.